# Call functions from different .js documents

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 2 functions of 2 types of different .js documents.

File1.js

```
$(document).ready(function Function1(){
    var $input = $("#input-country");
    $input.typeahead({source:['United States', 'China', 'Germany']});
});
```

File2.js

```
$(document).ready(function Function2(){
    var $input = $("#input-country");
    $input.typeahead({source:['Menu 1', 'Menu 2', 'Menu 3']});
});
```

I created a global js, which called the 2 functions, global.js

Global.js

```
$(function TestName() {
    Function1();
    Function2();
});
```

When importing the files, only what is in the order works.

```
<script src="js/File1.js"></script>
<script src="js/File2.js"></script>
```

In this case, only File1.js works, the second does not.

or

```
<script src="js/File2.js"></script>
<script src="js/File1.js"></script>
```

In this case, only File2.js works, the first does not.

Comment: Remove the .ready function wrapper from both files and leave it with only the Function1()

Comment: Remover ready()?

Comment: Don't wrap the functions you're using with the jQuery document.ready().

Comment: Both your files-codes are targeting the **same element**. What is your plan actually  for all this?

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup you can nest any number of DOM-ready handlers - that's not the issue here AFAICS

Comment: What is `typeahead`? A plugin? Have you tried to destroy the first instance (if exists) before applying the new one on the same element?

Comment: TestName () was to call the other two functions Function1 (), Function2 ()

Comment: Yes, typeahead, it is a plugin!

Comment: What does "works" mean?  In both `File1.js` and `File2.js`, you're calling named immediately invoked function expressions (**edit:** named callback function; my mistake).  Both of these should execute once, when the jQuery `$(document).ready` function is called.  In `Global.js`, you've got a bit of a mess.  I'm not sure if wrapping a function in a jQuery constructor is supposed to do anything, but if it does, it will certainly result in a `ReferenceError` for both `Function1` and `Function2`.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should try to avoid polluting the global name space where possible, however, shared functionality in a web browser can be achieved by assigning to the window object as follows:

```
// File 1 - using an immediately invoked function expression (IFFE)
(function(global) {
  // make available globally:
  global.funcOne = myFunc;

  var privateVariable = 1;

  function myFunc() {
    return privateVariable;
  }
}(window));

// File 2 - using an immediately invoked function expression (IFFE)
(function(global) {
  // make available globally: 
  global.funcTwo = myFunc;

  var privateVariable = 2;

  function myFunc() {
    return privateVariable;
  }   
}(window));

// your "global" js file (using the jquery document ready wrapper):
$(function() {
   console.log(funcOne() + funcTwo()); // returns 3
});
```

Here is a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6g8tpw6o/) which demonstrates this concept.

**Note**: The IFFE pattern is less common in as the latest release of [ECMAScript](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/) along with a [module bundler](http://requirejs.org/) allows us to do this more elegantly.

To show this working for your specific example, here is what I would do:

```
// File 1
(function(global, $) {
    // make available globally:
  global.setCountries = setCountries;
  // private variable:
  var data = {source:['United States', 'China', 'Germany']};
  function setCountries() {
    $("#input-country").typeahead(data);
    console.log('setCountries() Called!'); // not required.
  }
// dependencies:  
}(window, jquery));

// File 2
(function(global, $) {
    // expose global function:
  global.setMenu = setMenu;
    // private variable:
    var data = {source:['Menu 1', 'Menu 2', 'Menu 3']};
    // private function:
  function setMenu() {
    $("#input-country").typeahead(data);
    console.log('SetMenu() Called!'); // not required.
  }
// dependencies:
}(window, jquery));

// Global Js
$(function() {
   function TestName() { 
       setMenu();
       setCountries();
   }
   TestName();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The only problem that is occurring is that the two methods created, Function1 () and Function2 () are not being invoked through the TestName () method.

Comment: @Gean I've just updated my answer for you to solve that!

Comment: One moment Matt, I'll check it out!

Comment: Matt, did not solve my problem. When I type in the input, the typeahead function does not appear.

Comment: Any other tips?

Comment: @Gean can you provide a JSFiddle? It is very difficult to see how you are referencing `.typeahead`.

Comment: @Gean the question raised here is about calling functions in multiple files, this answer should handle this (you'll see the console logs). So, easier would be to mark this as complete and raise another question. I can then assist with that specific issue.